# Upgrade from SQL Server 2008 to 2017 causes date subtraction error on Access front end form using DCount

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2017

I inherited supporting a database from an employee that left the company years ago. The team that uses this is being forced to upgrade from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2017.

Everything seems to work fine but there is a form that has text boxes that show some counts of the data using a `DCount` function. The problem kicks in when it is trying to subtract today's date (using `Date()`) from a column `[DateReceived]` (of type `smalldatetime` in SQL Server) from the table in the `DCount` function.

This works

```
=DCount("[ClaimNum]","tblClaimsData","[ClaimStatus] = 'Open' and  #2/4/2021# - [DateReceived] between 45 and 59")
```

This throws an error

```
=DCount("[ClaimNum]","tblClaimsData","[ClaimStatus] = 'Open' and Date() - [DateReceived] between 60 and 90")
```

I cannot seem to figure out a workaround for the `Date()` function IF that is where the problem is. I have a query that will count the data table but I cannot have a query as a control source for a text box, nor can I get a value of another text box in place of the `Date()` in my `DCount` function.

Any thoughts here? Thanks!

[ODBC SQL subtraction error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WOol.png)

[Form with counts - the one that works has the date hard coded in the DCount function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIgzF.png)

Comment: Try using DateDiff function.

Comment: Tried that but DCount does not like DateDiff in the parameter string, indicates invalid syntax, entered operand w/o an operator, unless of course I did it wrong.  This is what I used -> =DCount("[MenloClaimNum]","tblClaimsData","[ClaimStatus] = 'Open' and DateDiff("d", Date(),[DateReceived]) between 45 and 59")

Comment: Use apostrophes instead of quotes for the `d` unit: `'d'`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, no error now but it does not calculate the value - returns a 0.

Comment: If it worked before, then ZERO need exists to change the syntax that ALSO worked before. I would double, triple, quadriple check the linked table and be 100%, 200%, 300%, 400% absolute sure, and BEYOND sure that when you open the linked table in design mode, that the datetime columns from sql server are being seen as datetime in the access client. It is possbile that during the sql update for some strange reason the datetime columns were changed to datetime2. If that occures, then you have to link the tables in access using native 17 or later drivers (or NOT use datetime2 - either choice works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is crystal clear. Your data type is now *DateTime2*, which the ODBC driver reads as text, causing any numeric date handling to fail.

Best option is to change the data type to *DateTime* and your code will work.

Else, convert the text dates to true dates:

```
=DCount("[ClaimNum]","tblClaimsData","[ClaimStatus] = 'Open' and Date() - DateValue([DateReceived]) between 60 and 90")
```

That may still fail, however, if the text dates contain milliseconds, like `2021-02-04 15:42:30.000`.

If so, these must be chopped off before converting.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.  Thought it was something like that but could not figure out the proper way to use the DateValue (plus I thought my error was coming from the Date() function and not the field)   - THANKS!!